# ImageMagick way too slow drawing text

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I've got ImageMagick drawing dots with coordinates on an image, but it's terribly slow.
For context, I'm making a program to move the mouse cursor by typing two keys.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
image=screen.jpg

chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789'
gap=30

dimensions="$(identify -format '%w %h\n' "$image")" || exit
width=${dimensions% *} height=${dimensions#* }

cmd="convert -pointsize 16 -fill red -draw '$(
    ychars="$chars"
    for y in $(seq $gap $gap "$((height-gap))"); do
        yc="${ychars%${ychars#?}}" ychars="${ychars#?}"
        xchars="$chars"
        for x in $(seq $gap $gap $((width-gap))); do
            xc="${xchars%${xchars#?}}" xchars="${xchars#?}"
            printf 'rectangle %s,%s %s,%s text %s,%s %s ' $((x-1)) $((y-1)) $((x+1)) $((y+1)) $((x+2)) $((y-2)) "$yc$xc"
        done
    done
)' $image result.jpg"

eval "$cmd"
```

It generates a command that will draw screen.jpg with coordinates, the result is result.jpg.
The command it generates looks like this (but much much longer):

```
convert -pointsize 16 -fill red -draw 'rectangle 29,29 31,31 text 32,28 aa rectangle 59,29 61,31 text 62,28 ab rectangle 89,29 91,31 text 92,28 ac rectangle 119,29 121,31 text 122,28 ad' screen.jpg coords.jpg
```

The command is generated instantly but ImageMagick takes over 7 seconds on my 1920 x 1080 screenshot (`taken using import -window root screen.jpg`).
I tried GraphicsMagick too with little difference.
Am I doing something stupid, why is it so slow?
How can I improve the performance?
I was hoping for under a second or two.
If nothing else works, I'll make an image of coordinates and slap it on instead, but I was hoping it could be dynamic.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave the size of your input image and some indication of what the result is. Thank you.

Comment: How many points? Tried [a script](https://pastebin.com/34QJbtXY) that generates [14406 dots with their coordinates](https://imgur.com/a/PPyoWcK) (so a pretty long `-draw` instruction). Runs in 9s on my Core I5 9400. That's 625 nanoseconds per dot with coordinates... not so slow!

Comment: Thanks guys, it'd be used on screenshots, likely 1920 x 1080. Maybe I was too optimistic, I thought it was pretty simple as far as graphics goes, but maybe image manipulation is different.

Comment: Don't know if there'd be any mileage in drawing 1/4 of the points on each of 4 horizontal bands of transparent background in parallel, then pasting the 4 bands on top of original.